# Can I reference the same BitBucket Repository under two different names for enable custom triggering on Azure DevOps Services YAML?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, bitbucket, azure-pipelines-yaml

You think is possible to reference the same BitBucket Repository under 2 different names with 2 different paths in order to achieve and trigger 2 different stages ? I want to build and publish 7 different microservices on K8s but the repos are only 3 (divided in subfolders) you this this can be achievable? The idea is to create different blocks of template one for each microservice. But during the template checkout the 3 macrorepository only (for dev purposes). Let me show you my idea.

```
 resources:
  repositories:
############## 3 BITBUCKET BIG REPOS ##############
  - repository: omni-omsf-api
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: OMNI-OMSF-BitBucket-SC
    name: ovsdev/omni-omsf-api
    trigger: none

  - repository: omni-omsf-extension
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: OMNI-OMSF-BitBucket-SC
    name: ovsdev/omni-omsf-extension
    trigger: none

  - repository: omni-omsf-core
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: OMNI-OMSF-BitBucket-SC
    name: ovsdev/omni-omsf-core
    trigger: none
###################################################
############# 7 SUB-REPOS ONLY FOR TRIGGERING #########
  - repository: ovs-api-service
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: OMNI-OMSF-BitBucket-SC
    name: ovsdev/omni-omsf-api
    trigger:
      branches: 
        include: 
        - release_qa 
        - master
      paths: 
        include: 
        - ovs-api-service/*

###################################################

stages:
- ${{ if or( and( eq( parameters.ovsapiservice, true), eq( variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual') ), eq( variables['Build.Repository.Name'], 'ovs-api-service') ) }}:
  - template: microservice-buildRelease.template.yml
    parameters:
      dockerFilePath: omni-omsf-api/ovs-api-service/Dockerfile
      dockerImageName: ovs-api-service
      tag: $(Build.BuildId)
      microservicename: ovs-api-service
- ${{ else }}:
  - stage:
    jobs:
      - job:
        steps:
          - task: Bash@3
            displayName: Showing folder hierarchy
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                tree $(Pipeline.Workspace)
```

Comment: I read your YAML definition, but I think the trigger section of bitbucket resources make no sense in your situation, see my answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

> Can I reference the same BitBucket Repository under two different
> names

**The answer is Yes.** Different alias can refer from the same repository.

> enable custom triggering on Azure DevOps Services YAML

I read the YAML definition you provided, if you are talking about trigger of the resources section, then **the answer is NO.**

It should be pointed out that the usage you are using does not exist.

Please check these official articles, both of them mentioned this point:

[resources.repositories.repository definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/resources-repositories-repository?view=azure-pipelines)

> trigger: trigger # CI trigger for this repository, no CI trigger if
> skipped (**only works for Azure Repos**).

[Triggers Usage in resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers)

> Repository resource triggers only work for Azure Repos Git
> repositories in the same organization at present. They do not work for
> GitHub or Bitbucket repository resources.

So trigger via resources section of YAML is unable to achieve, you can only set YAML on bitbucket side and the condition should based on common trigger [on bitbucket side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/bitbucket?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).